# Error loading custom spinner

Tags: android, spinner, android-spinner

I have a `Spinner` that need to feed with ID and description address.

```
private Spinner spnBairroPesquisa;
spnBairroPesquisa=(Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spnBairroPesquisa);
```

I am seeking information on the method:
    `listaBairro = bairroDAO.listaBairroPesquisa(this,bairroPOJO);`
and feeding a list `listaBairro` of object `BairroPOJO`

The following method that feeds the object list:

```
public List<BairroPOJO> listaBairroPesquisa(Context context, BairroPOJO bairro){
    List<BairroPOJO> listaBairro = new ArrayList<BairroPOJO>();
    try {
        conn = dataBase.getReadableDatabase();
        String query = "select * from "+bairro.TABELA+
                " where "+bairro.IDCLIENTE+"="+bairro.getIdcliente()+
                " and "+bairro.IDPESQUISA+"="+bairro.getIdpesquisa()+
                " and "+bairro.CPFOPERADOR+"="+bairro.getCpfoperador();

        Cursor cursor = conn.rawQuery(query, null);
        if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                cursor.moveToFirst();
                do {
                    bairroPOJO = new BairroPOJO();
bairroPOJO.setIdbairro(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(bairroPOJO.IDBAIRRO)));
                    bairroPOJO.setDescricaoBairro(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(bairroPOJO.DESCRICAOBAIRRO)));
                    bairroPOJO.setCodigoBairro(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(bairroPOJO.CODIGOBAIRRO)));
                    bairroPOJO.setIdcliente(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(bairroPOJO.IDCLIENTE)));
                    bairroPOJO.setIdpesquisa(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(bairroPOJO.IDPESQUISA)));
                    bairroPOJO.setCpfoperador(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(bairroPOJO.CPFOPERADOR)));
                    listaBairro.add(bairroPOJO);
                } while (cursor.moveToNext());
            }
        }
        conn.close();
    }catch (Exception ex){

    }
    return listaBairro;
}
```

After step list and the layout created to feed the `ArrayAdapter` adpBairro :

```
adpBairro = new ArrayAdapter<BairroPOJO>(this, R.layout.list_adp_bairropesquisa,listaBairro);
    adpBairro.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.bairro_item_spinner);
```

But when I populate the data adapter in the `Spinner` I got  `NullPointException` error:

```
spnBairroPesquisa.setAdapter(adpBairro);
```

Please help me in this problem.

UPDATE, Follow my logcat:

```
08-27 21:09:37.101 1293-1293/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                             java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{br.com.wgti.wgadvisor/br.com.wgti.wgadvisor.UI.actFormularioUI}: java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
                                                 at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                              Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                 at br.com.wgti.wgadvisor.UI.actFormularioUI.alimentaSpinnerBairro(actFormularioUI.java:1016)
                                                 at br.com.wgti.wgadvisor.UI.actFormularioUI.onCreate(actFormularioUI.java:226)
                                                 at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
                                                 at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084) 
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130) 
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195) 
                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745) 
                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786) 
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553) 
                                                 at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Please change your title, it is very confusing

Comment: @BlackMagic remember you can suggest edits to owner. If he likes he will approve.

Comment: @WilkeGutierre can you provide logcat too please

Comment: I changed the title. This is the logcat :

Comment: The error more precisely, is the time that is set for the adpBairro spnBairroPesquisa .